# How to use a organized schedule in 4 agendas inside org (emacs)

Tags: emacs, org-mode

Is there something already coded for ORG (emacs) something that helps to create the Eisenhower Matrix?

[image: Four quadrants: urgent and important, urgent not important, not urgent but important, neither important nor urgent]
I know that can be done in the agenda creating 4 different files, or with some work, but it's possible to use the agenda of the ORG to separate them in 4 quadrants, like the image above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to give an alternative way of organizing the tasks based only in the priorities... I like this because let me decide when to change the tasks category (not automatic using the DEADLINE):

```lisp
;About the 2 elisp lines below: If you want to send items without explicit 
;priorities to the bottom of the list you have to set org-default-priority to the 
;value of org-lowest-priority). I did this to make recognize that: PRIORITY=0 are 
;items without explicit priorities (not A, B or C, but just TODO)
(setq org-lowest-priority ?E)
(setq org-default-priority ?E)

(add-to-list 'org-agenda-custom-commands
             '("e" "Eisenhower matrix"
               ((tags-todo
                 "+PRIORITY=\"A\""
                 ((org-agenda-overriding-header "Urgent and important")))
                (tags-todo
                 "+PRIORITY=\"B\""
                 ((org-agenda-overriding-header "Important but not urgent")))
                (tags-todo
                 "+PRIORITY=\"C\""
                 ((org-agenda-overriding-header "Urgent but not important")))
                (tags-todo
         "+PRIORITY=0-PRIORITY=\"A\"-PRIORITY=\"B\"-PRIORITY=\"C\""
                 ((org-agenda-overriding-header "Neither important nor urgent"))))
               nil))
```

Using that, the following org-mode file:

```
* TODO [#A] This is important and urgent
DEADLINE: <2021-03-11 Thu>
* TODO [#A] This is important but not urgent
DEADLINE: <2021-03-13 Sat>
* TODO This has no priority but is urgent
DEADLINE: <2021-03-11 Thu>
* TODO [#B] This has medium priority but is urgent
DEADLINE: <2021-03-11 Thu>
* TODO [#C] This has low priority but is urgent
DEADLINE: <2021-03-11 Thu>
* TODO [#A] This is important but has no deadline
* TODO This has no priority and is not urgent
DEADLINE: <2021-03-13 Sat>
* TODO [#B] This has medium priority and is not urgent
DEADLINE: <2021-03-13 Sat>
* TODO [#C] This has low priority and is not urgent
DEADLINE: <2021-03-13 Sat>
* TODO This has no priority and no deadline
* TODO [#B] This has medium priority and no deadline
* TODO [#C] This has low priority and no deadline
```

looks like this:

```
Urgent and important
  refile:     TODO [#A] This is important and not urgent: ver como adicionar os aniversários no ORG
  refile:     TODO [#A] This is important and urgent
  refile:     TODO [#A] This is important but not urgent
  refile:     TODO [#A] This is important but has no deadline

=============================================================================================================================
Important but not urgent
  refile:     TODO [#B] This has medium priority but is urgent
  refile:     TODO [#B] This has medium priority and is not urgent
  refile:     TODO [#B] This has medium priority and no deadline

=============================================================================================================================
Urgent but not important
  refile:     TODO [#C] This has low priority but is urgent
  refile:     TODO [#C] This has low priority and is not urgent
  refile:     TODO [#C] This has low priority and no deadline

=============================================================================================================================
Neither important nor urgent
  refile:     TODO This has no priority but is urgent
  refile:     TODO This has no priority and is not urgent
  refile:     TODO This has no priority and no deadline
```

Answer (score 2):

I came up with this custom agenda command, that considers anything with priority A to be "important", and anything with a deadline within the next two days to be "urgent":

```lisp
(add-to-list 'org-agenda-custom-commands
             '("e" "Eisenhower matrix"
               ((tags-todo
                 "+PRIORITY=\"A\"+DEADLINE<=\"<+2d>\""
                 ((org-agenda-overriding-header "Urgent (within 2 days) and important")))
                (tags-todo
                 "+PRIORITY=\"A\"+DEADLINE>\"<+2d>\"|+PRIORITY=\"A\"-DEADLINE={.}"
                 ((org-agenda-overriding-header "Important but not urgent")))
                (tags-todo
                 "-PRIORITY=\"A\"+DEADLINE<=\"<+2d>\""
                 ((org-agenda-overriding-header "Urgent (within 2 days) but not important")))
                (tags-todo
                 "-PRIORITY=\"A\"+DEADLINE>\"<+2d>\"|-PRIORITY=\"A\"-DEADLINE={.}"
                 ((org-agenda-overriding-header "Neither important nor urgent"))))
               nil))
```

Using that, the following org-mode file:

```
* TODO [#A] This is important and urgent
DEADLINE: <2021-03-11 Thu>
* TODO [#A] This is important but not urgent
DEADLINE: <2021-03-13 Sat>
* TODO This has no priority but is urgent
DEADLINE: <2021-03-11 Thu>
* TODO [#B] This has medium priority but is urgent
DEADLINE: <2021-03-11 Thu>
* TODO [#C] This has low priority but is urgent
DEADLINE: <2021-03-11 Thu>
* TODO [#A] This is important but has no deadline
* TODO This has no priority and is not urgent
DEADLINE: <2021-03-13 Sat>
* TODO [#B] This has medium priority and is not urgent
DEADLINE: <2021-03-13 Sat>
* TODO [#C] This has low priority and is not urgent
DEADLINE: <2021-03-13 Sat>
* TODO This has no priority and no deadline
* TODO [#B] This has medium priority and no deadline
* TODO [#C] This has low priority and no deadline
```

looks like this:

```
Urgent (within 2 days) and important
  test:       TODO [#A] This is important and urgent

======================================================================================================================
Important but not urgent
  test:       TODO [#A] This is important but not urgent
  test:       TODO [#A] This is important but has no deadline

======================================================================================================================
Urgent (within 2 days) but not important
  test:       TODO This has no priority but is urgent
  test:       TODO [#B] This has medium priority but is urgent
  test:       TODO [#C] This has low priority but is urgent

======================================================================================================================
Neither important nor urgent
  test:       TODO This has no priority and is not urgent
  test:       TODO [#B] This has medium priority and is not urgent
  test:       TODO This has no priority and no deadline
  test:       TODO [#B] This has medium priority and no deadline
  test:       TODO [#C] This has low priority and is not urgent
  test:       TODO [#C] This has low priority and no deadline
```

Answer (score 1):

I like Lucas' answer but I'd prefer the inline priorities of agenda items to be more explicit than A, B, C and D, which I find to be too abstract. I want them to be:

```
 [IMPORTANT✅ URGENT✅] 
 [IMPORTANT✅ urgent❌]
 [important❌ URGENT✅] 
 [important❌ urgent❌]
```

So incorporating Lucas' answer into a setup for the [Org Fancy Priorities](https://github.com/harrybournis/org-fancy-priorities) package, which allows one to use strings to represent priorities. I'm set up with the following:

```
(use-package org-fancy-priorities
  :ensure t
  :hook
  (org-mode . org-fancy-priorities-mode)
  :config
  (setq org-fancy-priorities-list
    '((?A . "[IMPORTANT✅ URGENT✅]")
      (?B . "[IMPORTANT✅ urgent❌]")
      (?C . "[important❌ URGENT✅]")
      (?D . "[important❌ urgent❌]")))
  (setq org-priority-highest ?A
        org-priority-lowest ?D
        org-priority-default ?D)
  (add-to-list 'org-agenda-custom-commands
               '("e" "Eisenhower matrix"
                 ((tags-todo
                   "+PRIORITY=\"A\""
                   ((org-agenda-overriding-header "IMPORTANT AND URGENT")))
                  (tags-todo
                   "+PRIORITY=\"B\""
                   ((org-agenda-overriding-header "IMPORTANT BUT NOT URGENT")))
                  (tags-todo
                   "+PRIORITY=\"C\""
                   ((org-agenda-overriding-header "NOT IMPORTANT BUT URGENT")))
                  (tags-todo
                   "+PRIORITY=\"D\""
                   ((org-agenda-overriding-header "NEITHER IMPORTANT NOR URGENT"))))
                 nil)))
```

Now as well as having the option for an Eisenhower Matrix, my regular agenda reads along the lines of...

```
  todos:      17:00-18:30 TODO [IMPORTANT✅ URGENT✅] German course
  todos:      TODO [IMPORTANT✅ urgent❌] Do Elisp exercises
```